# Building DataFrame Column Names From List Generates Invalid Names

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a dataframe with column names from a list. However, it is treating my column names as invalid, and so is adding `X.` in front of them. The names should be valid. What is going on?

Example:

```
col_names = list("A", "A95", "p", "NN")
df = data.frame(col_names)
```

Output:

```
  X.A. X.A95. X.p. X.NN.
1    A    A95    p    NN
```

Also, how do I get the contents of these columns to be empty or NA (pereferably without writing `models = list("A"=NA, "A95"=NA, "p"=NA, etc...` for each variable)?

Edit: Found a 2 liner workaround.

```
df = data.frame(col_names)
setNames(df, col_names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is not odd, it is as documented. You are trying to convert a list to a data frame, saying nothing about the names of the variables. The variable names are inferred from the contents, and an "X" is added to each name, as in:

```
> data.frame(as.list(1:5))
#     X1L X2L X3L X4L X5L 
#  1   1   2   3   4   5
```

or:

```
> data.frame(as.list(as.numeric(1:5)))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  2  3  4  5
```

Fortunately, there is `setNames`, so you can do:

```
cn <- list("A", "A95", "p", "NN")
df <- as.data.frame(setNames(cn,cn))
df
#    A A95 p NN
#  1 A A95 p NN
```

Ok, to have the contents appear as `NA` you can do either...

```
df[] <- NA
```

or, from the start:

```
df <- as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(rep(NA,4)), cn))
```

Comment: alternatively `setNames(rep(list(NA),4), cn)` (that is, `as.list(rep(NA,4))` is equivalent to `rep(list(NA),4)`

Answer (score 1):

What about using `dplyr` to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

col_names = list("A", "A95", "p", "NN")
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 4)) %>% setNames(nm = c(col_names))
```

Output:

```
> df
[1] A   A95 p   NN 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a fine workaround. I'm still curious why I'm getting the odd behavior though.